# How to update a collection based on another collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Now I get two collections: `coll01` and `coll02`.

And the structure of coll01 is like this:

```
{
  id: 01,
  name: "xxx",
  age: 30
}
```

and the structure of coll02 is like:

```
{
  id: 01,
  name: "XYZ"
  gender: "male"
}
```

The two id fields in the both collection are indices. And the numbers of documents in these two collections are same.

And what I want to do in traditional SQL is :

```
update coll01, coll02
set coll01.name = coll02.name
where coll01.id = coll02.id
```

Comment: This is a very common use case for mongo. When going from SQL to Mongo, often you need to update the int IDs with Mongo ObjectIDs. I don't care what data you're working with-- all data related and is relational. Person documents (and sub-documents) have to correlate order documents somehow.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Mongodb is not relational database and doesn't support join's. So, you should think a little, do you really need mongodb for your purposes?

Solution for update: you can update each document from `coll01` in loop:

```
db.coll01.find().forEach(function (doc1) {
    var doc2 = db.coll02.findOne({ id: doc1.id }, { name: 1 });
    if (doc2 != null) {
        doc1.name = doc2.name;
        db.coll01.save(doc1);
    }
});
```

Index for `id` field in `coll02` collection will decrease `find()` operation execution time inside the loop. Also, see about server-side JavaScript execution: [Running .js files via a mongo shell Instance on the Server](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/server-side-javascript/#running-js-scripts-in-mongo-on-mongod-host)

Comment: u missing a $and in the query mate

Comment: you should use findOne instead of find, find returns a cursor to the selected documents.