# How can I split a MongoDB collection into 3 and assign a new field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a json collection with 300 records like this:

```
{
  salesNumber: 23839,
  batch: null
},
{
  salesNumber 389230,
  batch: null
}
...etc.
```

I need to divide this collection into 3 different batches.  So, when sorted by salesNumber, the first 100 would be in batch 1, the next 100 would be batch 2, and the last 100 would be batch 3.  How do I do this?

I wrote a script to select the first 100, but when I tried to turn it into an array to use in an update, the result was 0 records.

```
var firstBatchCompleteRecords = db.properties.find(
{
    "auction":  ObjectId("50")
}
).sort("saleNumber").limit(100);
// This returned 174 records as excepted with all the fields

var firstBatch = firstBatchCompleteRecords.distinct( "saleNumber", {});
// This returned 0 records
```

I was going to take the results of that last query and use it in an update statement:

```
db.properties.update(
{
    "saleNumber":
     {
          "$in": firstBatch
    }
}
,
{
    $set: 
        {
            batch: "1"
        }
}
,
{
    multi: true
}
);
```

...then I would have created an array using distinct of the next 100 and update those, but I never got that far.

Comment: Did you try the `distinct` method with only 1 argument and without the `{}` in the query parameter?

Comment: Are you doing this in the shell or you are using a language driver?

Answer (score 0):

there is a chance to get results using aggregation framework - and store them in new collection - then you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19823548/5919473) to iterate and update fields in source collection

Have a fun!

```
db.sn.aggregate([{
            $sort : {
                salesNumber : 1
            }
        }, {
            $group : {
                _id : null,
                arrayOfData : {
                    $push : "$$ROOT"
                },

            }
        }, {
            $project : {
                _id : 0,
                firstHundred : {
                    $slice : ["$arrayOfData", 0, 100]
                },
                secondHundred : {
                    $slice : ["$arrayOfData", 99, 100]
                },
                thirdHundred : {
                    $slice : ["$arrayOfData", 199, 100]
                },
            }
        }, {
            $project : {
                "firstHundred.batch" : {
                    $literal : 1
                },
                "firstHundred.salesNumber" : 1,
                "firstHundred._id" : 1,

                "secondHundred.batch" : {
                    $literal : 2
                },
                "secondHundred.salesNumber" : 1,
                "secondHundred._id" : 1,

                "thirdHundred.batch" : {
                    $literal : 3
                },
                "thirdHundred.salesNumber" : 1,
                "thirdHundred._id" : 1,
            }
        }, {
            $project : {
                allValues : {
                    $setUnion : ["$firstHundred", "$secondHundred", "$thirdHundred"]
                }
            }
        }, {
            $unwind : "$allValues"
        }, {
            $project : {
                _id : "$allValues._id",
                salesNumber : "$allValues.salesNumber",
                batch : "$allValues.batch",
            }
        }, {
            $out : "collectionName"
        }
    ])

db.collectionName.find()
```

> and output generated for 6 document divided by 2:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5733ade7eeeccba2bd546121"),
    "salesNumber" : 389230,
    "batch" : 2
}, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5733ade7eeeccba2bd546120"),
    "salesNumber" : 23839,
    "batch" : 1
}, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5733ade7eeeccba2bd546122"),
    "salesNumber" : 43839,
    "batch" : 1
}, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5733ade7eeeccba2bd546124"),
    "salesNumber" : 63839,
    "batch" : 2
}, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5733ade7eeeccba2bd546123"),
    "salesNumber" : 589230,
    "batch" : 3
}, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5733ade7eeeccba2bd546125"),
    "salesNumber" : 789230,
    "batch" : 3
}
```

Any comments welcome!