# nodejs, mongodb find with forEach and update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, promise, find

I have problem with using forEach and update,

I want to update A collection with B collection's docs.
For example,

```
db.collection(B).find().toArray(function(err, result) {
    ....
    result.forEach(doc){
        ....
        db.collection(A).updateOne(query...){
        }
    }
}
```

and also, B is not only one colleciton. In my code, B is array and B = [B1, B2, B3 ... ]. (not my real value name is B. just example)

I want to use Promise or async, but I don't know how to use.

```
for(i = 0; i < B.length; i++)
    also as same upper code
```

Is there any ideas or methods, can fix this problem? T.T..

my B's doc field like this.

```
{_id:ObjectId(..), value1:[a, b], value2:"ccc"}
```

and from this, I extract x from a, y from b, z from value2;
and what i want A's doc field like this,

```
{_id:ObjectId(..), x : x, y : y, z : z, ids:[id1]}
```

from B, while get each column, it match x, y, z just add ids array like

```
{_id:ObjectId(..), x : x, y : y, z : z, ids:[id1, id2]}
```

it doesn't match x, y, z, just insert

```
{_id:ObjectId(..), x : x, y : y, z : z, ids:[id1]}.]
```

I used updateOne(query, value, upsert)

```
query : {x:x, y:y, z:z}
value : {$set:{x:x, y:y, z:z}, $addToSet:{ids:{$each:{id}}}}
upsert : {upsert:true}
```

Comment: Instead of looping use [`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) operation

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet thanks! I will search for that and I will try to my code

Answer (score 0):

Example: Update collection `A` with `B`

```
 db.getCollection('B').find().forEach(function (doc1) {
    var updateData = {x :doc1.value1[0], y:doc1.value1[1], z: doc1.value2 };
    var doc2 = db.getCollection('A').findOne(updateData);
    if (doc2 != null) {
         db.getCollection('A').update(updateData,{ $addToSet: { 'ids': doc1._id }})
    }else{
         updateData.ids = [doc1._id];
         db.getCollection('A').save(updateData);
    }

});
```

Reference Link : [How to update a collection based on another collection in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822871/how-to-update-a-collection-based-on-another-collection-in-mongodb)

Comment: I do not use doc1 directly to A, I have to modify doc1 to convert some value and then some values insert to A. I will search save function right now!

Comment: I have question about your answer, Is it okay collection A and B is completely other collection?

Comment: Ya, Its work. I have tested in a local using "MongoDB management tool"

Comment: sure, i will happy to help you

Comment: I'm really thanks for you. My update method like this, if match query docs doesn't exists, just insert doc1. But exist, update A's matched doc1. but one of doc1's field(ids) is array type. when I use save function, it doesn't work  append ids filed T.T..

Comment: When I got B's doc, transform doc to x, y, z. And I want to insert/update A's doc with query is match {x: x, y: y, z:z}. It matches my query (A has {x: x, y: y, z:z} fileds then I just want to append ids field ({x: x, y: y, z:z, ids:[id1, id2]}, just id2 appended). but it doesn't match, I want insert {x: x, y: y, z:z, ids:[id]}

Comment: Update your question with example data of collection and which ids you need to insert?

Comment: yep! wait a minute plz.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I will try that! have a nice day